# IBinder parameter to onServiceConnection() is null

Tags: service, aidl

At present I have server(service) client(activity) working project which are operated in a same process. I am trying to move the server to a new process by adding android:process=":seperateService" in the manifest.

However, after successful bind to service, in function

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1)
```

the arg1 parameter received is null. This appears only when the service is made to have separates processes.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

solved by using:
**aidl = binder.Stub.asInterface(arg1);**

instead of:
**aidl = (binder) arg1;**

but not sure of why this is was not problem when both client and server in same process.